# Android IInputConnectionWrapper warning on orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, warnings

I have an activity with a GLSurfaceView in it:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  private View mDecorView;
  private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(getAssets()));
    setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);}
  }
}
```

Nothing complicated, I just hide the status, menu bars and the navigation bar and I also lock the activity in landscape mode. However, every time the app loses focus when the phone is held in portrait mode, I get a **W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection** in logcat. I am using Android Studio. What is this caused by and how do I fix it?

Also, since I don't use any menus, should I remove the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected functions? If I don't use action bars, should I extend from Activity instead of ActionBarActivity? I have seen people extend from FragmentActivity, but I haven't used fragments yet and I don't know what they are for. What would be the best parent class to use?